# Is it possible how to two forms submit by one button and then two forms perform two different actions?

Tags: javascript, php

I have to tried JavaScript.But it performs one form action only.Please explain how to an one button using two forms in same page.

I have to use the below code:

```js
function my()
{
 document.schedule.action = "firstaction";
 document.schedule.target = "_blank";    
 document.schedule.submit();            
 return true;
}
function my1()
{
    document.consultant.action = "secondaction";
    document.consultant.target = "_blank";    
    document.consultant.submit();             
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't submit two forms at once without using AJAX.

Comment: The key question is: why would you want to do that? Please give an example of your intended use-case so we can see if there is some better advice that we can give about how to achieve what you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Parallax form submissions are not possible**

Because form submission means loading new page, so browse close all exiting connections like your previous form submission.

**solution**

Use ajax

```
function my()
{
   $.ajax({
    url:document.schedule.action,
    type:'post',
    data:$(document.schedule).serialize()
  });  
 return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

submit() would submit the form the normal way, thus reloading the page before the other/second form could be submitted. To do what you want use Ajax
A jQuery Ajax example:

```
$("#form1").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("functions.php", {key1:"value1", key2:"value2"}, function(data){
        //submit the second form here using the same $.post method
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the solution.

You can do something like this:

```
<form class="myform">
  <!-- form 1 fields -->
</form>

<form class="myform">
  <!-- form 2 fields -->
</form>
```

And using JQuery

```
$('.myform').sumit(function(e)) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // FORM VALIDATION

    // Form 1 function
    $.ajax({
        url: "action1",
    }).success(function() {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });

    // Form 2 function
    $.ajax({
        url: "action2",
    }).success(function() {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
}
```

Btw in my opinion you don't need anymore two forms but just one.

Comment: I will try using ajax

Comment: how to use ajax for two forms??

Comment: how to send request and response? and then if having anyother methods?

Comment: Man... I can't write your code... take a look here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ of how ajax works...